# Jquery slider cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies, slider

I'm using a jquery 'coda slider' plugin...

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html

I would really like the position of the slider to be remembered when visitors click away from the page and return. I've looked at some examples, but I'm really unsure of how to apply it to a slider..I don't want the cookie to remain in the same position for the whole browser session, just to remember the last slide the user was on...Does anyone have any ideas how I could add a cookie to a jquery slider? :S

Answer (score 0):

I used this guys blog to get me started, http://blog.devonlinux.net/2009/10/10/remember-jcarousel-position/ , it needed to be chopped together but it had the basics. Guess you probably found a solution already by now, I am slow ^^